# How does yum work with "enabled=0" of repo files?

Tags: software-installation, yum, repository

yum access to  ‘repodata’ from URL address in `/etc/yum.conf` or `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo`

but when i verify them in my centos :

In yum.conf there is not URL of repodata

Also repo files in this path `/etc/yum.repos.d` include URLs,
many of them are disable with this flag `enabled=0` and others do not have `enabled` flag

But i am using yum and it works good ! how does my yum work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default an entry in a repo file is *enabled*

eg

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
# baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

There is no `enabled` line in this configuration and so the repo is enabled.

You can see what repo's are enabled with

```
yum repolist enabled
```

To temporarily enable a repo that's normally disabled you can use the `--enablerepo` option

eg

```
yum --enablerepo=foobar install xyz
```

Comment: thank you,what are $releaseve $basearch?

Comment: It's described in the `man yum.conf` page and is a value that defines the CentOS release version you're running.  eg `7` for CentOS7.  Can be determined by running `yum whatprovides  'system-release(releasever)'` but normally you don't need to worry about it.